# Is there any open source projects that employs linq within?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, open-source

I am on my way of linq learning and would like to see how linq is applied in the real world projects. So is there anyone who can suggest some open source C# and VB projects that employs Linq technology within?

Comment: I myself know one: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

Comment: The majority is the c# ones, VB ones seem a lot less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have not checked it yet, I think **[SubSonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/)** is one in my TODO List to study. I assume it will have lot of Linq techniques.

Answer (score 2):

I have found [MOQ](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) a very interesting project. It takes full advantage of .NET 3.5 (i.e. Linq expression trees) and C# 3.0 features (i.e. lambda expressions).

Answer (score 1):

I think NHibernate.Linq will be a good lesson.

you can download the code [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/)

Answer (score 1):

Whereas authors of open source application often want to develop crossplatform application they tend to use .Net/Mono compatible features. The number of "LINQ-equipped" open source application will increasing after normal implementation of LINQ in Mono.